# SUM selling price by day of the week

Tags: mysql

I've found perfect code for my solution, but sadly I haven't found a way to add there one small addition which would `SUM` `selling_price` for that exact day.

SQL Code:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(WEEKDAY(`date`) = 0 OR NULL) AS Mon,
  COUNT(WEEKDAY(`date`) = 1 OR NULL) AS Tue,
  COUNT(WEEKDAY(`date`) = 2 OR NULL) AS Wed,
  COUNT(WEEKDAY(`date`) = 3 OR NULL) AS Thu,
  COUNT(WEEKDAY(`date`) = 4 OR NULL) AS Fri,
  COUNT(WEEKDAY(`date`) = 5 OR NULL) AS Sat,
  COUNT(WEEKDAY(`date`) = 6 OR NULL) AS Sun
FROM orders
WHERE `date` >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL ( WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE()) ) DAY
  AND `date` <  CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: update your question with a proper data sample and the expected result  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SUM(IF(WEEKDAY(`date`) = 0,selling_price,0)) AS Mon_Price
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I just tried to get IF working myself kept throwing me errors. Will accept the answer in second.